# When will the method "onPrepareOptionsMenu" be called?

Tags: android, android-activity

I create a menu.xml , only one action item with the "always" inside it.
now I want to use the this method to change the menu's visible ,remove old action item , add new action item , change the old action item's icon ...
 so how to implement this ? 
I don't want the onCreateOptionMenu to be called more than once as the activity has presented by Android system.

Answer (score 1):

`onPrepareOptionsMenu()` will be called automatically after `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

And if you called `invalidateOptionsMenu()` on any action-item click event, then, it will be called again.

Comment: the onCreateOptionMenu() will be called as you see, the invalidateOptionMenu() is used for the onCreateOptionMenu()